# iOS App rejected because of GestureRecognizer subclasses

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, uigesturerecognizer

I tried to submit my app to AppStore but got rejected with motivation:

Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

```
UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer, UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer
```

The only place where I can find this strings is in MHVideoPhotoGallery pod. There it using like:

```
 if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer")]|| [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer")] ) {
        return YES;
    }
```

I created an issue for this (https://github.com/mariohahn/MHVideoPhotoGallery/issues/156), but don't get response. But this is popular pod project, if Apple rejected apps because of it - would not it be widely known? What can I do with this situation?